# Reference for Complex Manifolds for Great Picard Theorem and Julia Sets

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, complex-manifolds

I’ve recently been looking to understand the proofs of some theorems about complex analysis and Julia sets that require results on complex manifolds, especially The Great Picard Theorem. I need The Uniformization Theorem, then I need to understand why the plane with two points removed can’t have the entire complex plane as its cover. I know basic complex analysis, real differential topology and results on coverings from algebraic topology. Where can I find a text with the sort of results I need?

Comment: any good book on Riemann surfaces. Be warned, proving the uniformization theorem (at least the ways I've read) requires building up a fair bit of theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once one knows the uniformization theorem, the universal cover $\widetilde{X}$ of $X =\mathbb{C} - \{p_1, p_2\}$ is a simply connected noncompact Riemann surface and so is uniformized to either $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{D}$. As the universal cover of $X$, $\pi_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z} *\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $\widetilde{X}$ by holomorphic automorphisms. Any holomorphic automorphism of the plane is affine complex-linear, i.e. $z \mapsto az + b, a \neq 0$. One can check that the group of affine complex-linear maps of $\mathbb{C}$ contains no $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$ subgroup, which rules out the possibility.

Proofs of the uniformization theorem all require substantial machinery on Riemann surfaces. Many people starting studying subjects that use the uniformization theorem as a tool treat it as a black box for a while and come back to it once they have decided to specialize in the field. Learning a proof of it is an investment of energy that does not give a particularly good feeling if one wants to pursue a PhD in complex dynamics, for instance.

If you want to read a proof of the uniformization theorem, I am partial to Donaldson's proof in his book *Riemann Surfaces.* It uses differential forms and some techniques that are more broadly useful. Its main tool is a "main theorem" for Riemann surfaces about inversion of the Laplacian. This theorem can be read in Donaldson. I learned it from Royden's article *Function Theory on Riemann Surfaces,* which is a great paper if one is interested in Riemann surfaces and has some background on analysis and differential geometry (e.g. Stokes' theorem, ${L}^2$).